# Longest Valid Parentheses

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Given a string containing just the characters '(' and ')', find the length of the longest valid (well-formed) parentheses substring.

I have implemented below code.

```
public int LongestValidParentheses(string s) {
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return 0;
    int longest = 0;
    int tempLongest = 0;
    bool lastValid = false;
    
    Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++){
        if(s[i] == '('){
            stack.Push(s[i]);
            if(!lastValid)
                tempLongest = 0;
        }
        else{
            if(stack.Count > 0){
                stack.Pop();
                tempLongest += 2;
                lastValid = true;
            }
        }
        longest = Math.Max(longest, tempLongest);
    }
    
    return longest;
}
```

It seems to be working for most cases "(()", ")()())", ")(()()(())", "((())))))((("

Getting incorrect output for "()(()"

Result I got: 4

Expected: 2

Any clue what I am missing in the logic? I have access to working solution but I would appreciate if someone helps me identify the issue in my code.

Comment: The cases where it works have the same length regardless of whether the subsequence is required to be contiguous. Can you confirm that "substring" has its usual meaning (contiguous subsequence of a string)?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat The valid sequence has to be contiguous but not a subsequence though. At any position if an invalid parentheses is added, it would break the running count and longest contiguous substring will be recorded till then. The count will start again and accumulate till valid. At every invalid break max accumulated count will be taken. So in this case: "()(()" the longest would be 2 as we have a break in the middle.

Comment: If your for loop completes, and if still stack has elements then it is invalid expression.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Here I need to get the longest possible substring which is valid.

Comment: ()(() : 2 , (() : 2 ,())))) : 2 , )(()()(()) : 6 , ((())))))((( : 6  , are these expected outputs?  In your present code, there is no place where the `lastValid` is reset to false.

Answer (score 0):

See if the below code suits your expected outputs. In your code there was no check to reset the `lastValid` flag in order to break the running count. I have handled it in a different way. Whenever we encounter a breakage in valid, we could remove one item from the stack.

Code:

```
public int LongestValidParentheses(string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) 
        return 0;
    int longest = 0;
    int tempLongest = 0;
    bool lastValid = false;

    Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
    int exprLen = s.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < exprLen; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '(')
        {
            stack.Push(s[i]);
            //if (!lastValid)
              //  tempLongest = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                stack.Pop();
                tempLongest += 2;
                if (stack.Count > 0)
                {
                    //we are the end, but still if there is items on stack
                    //except if there is only a pair, deduct
                    if (tempLongest ==4 && (exprLen - i) == 1)
                    {
                        if (stack.Count == 1)
                            tempLongest -= 2;
                    }
                    //lastValid = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //lastValid = false;
                if(stack.Count>0)
                    stack.Pop();
                tempLongest = 0;
            }
        }
        longest = Math.Max(longest, tempLongest);
    }
    return longest;
}
```

Test results:
parens  ()(() : 2

parens  (() : 2

parens  ())))) : 2

parens  ((((() : 2

parens  ((((()() : 4

parens  )(()()(()) : 8

parens  ((())))))((( : 6

Answer (score 0):

this is an beetter approch which solves it on O(n) and in one go

```
public class Solution {
public int longestValidParentheses(String s) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    int max=0;
    int left = -1;
    for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
        if(s.charAt(j)=='(') stack.push(j);            
        else {
            if (stack.isEmpty()) left=j;
            else{
                stack.pop();
                if(stack.isEmpty()) max=Math.max(max,j-left);
                else max=Math.max(max,j-stack.peek());
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

}